# Creating a global SQLite DB Connection with Singleton pattern in Swift

Tags: swift, design-patterns, sqlite.swift

I detect whether a connection exists on a Singleton instance and if it doesn't it will open up a new connection on app start up. However, ideally I'd like for the open function to fire when the Singleton is first created without having to explicitly call it and assign it to some variable within the class.

The way I have the code now it defeats the purpose of having a shared Singleton because I just access the static connection object. When I attempt to change the static `conn` to an instance variable I get the error `Instance member 'conn' cannot be used on type 'DBConnection'`

**Non-working code**

```swift
class DBConnection {
    static let shared = DBConnection()
    var conn: Connection? = nil
    
    private init() { }
    
    static func open(dbPath: URL) throws {
        var dbConnections: [Connection] = []
        
        do {
            let dbConnection = try Connection("\(dbPath)/db.sqlite3")
            dbConnections.append(dbConnection)
            print("found connection, \(dbConnections)")
        } catch {
            throw SQLiteDBError.couldNotOpenConnection
        }
        
        self.conn = dbConnections[0]
        print("successfully opened connection")
    }
}
```

How can you call a private function within a Singleton class on init and assign it to some variable?

**Current working code**

```swift
class DBConnection {
    static let shared = DBConnection()
    static var conn: Connection?
    
    private init() { }
    
    static func open(dbPath: URL) throws {
        var dbConnections: [Connection] = []
        
        do {
            let dbConnection = try Connection("\(dbPath)/db.sqlite3")
            dbConnections.append(dbConnection)
            print("found connection, \(dbConnections)")
        } catch {
            throw SQLiteDBError.couldNotOpenConnection
        }
        
        self.conn = dbConnections[0]
        print("successfully opened connection")
    }
}
```

Main app init

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    init() {
        if DBConnection.conn != nil {
            do {
                try DBConnection.open(dbPath: FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)[0])
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        } else {
            print("Connection already existed")
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Will dbPath change often or is it always the same? If it is the same you could call the method from init.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson dbPath will always be the same

Comment: Then remove the parameter in `open` and call it from `init`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you I'll try it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I attempt to change the static conn to an instance variable I get the error `Instance member 'conn' cannot be used on type 'DBConnection'`

That makes sense considering how you're using `open`:

```
try DBConnection.open(dbPath: FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)[0])
```

Right now, `open` is a static method of `DBConnection`, which means that you can call it without needing an instance of the class. It's similar to a "class method" in Objective-C. But in your broken code, you have:

> var conn: Connection? = nil

so `conn` is an instance variable, i.e. a variable that only exists in the context of an instance of the class. A quick fix would be to make `open` non-static:

```
func open(dbPath: URL) throws {
```

and then call it using the shared instance:

```
try DBConnection.shared.open(dbPath: FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)[0])
```

(Note the `shared` added there.)

> However, ideally I'd like for the open function to fire when the Singleton is first created without having to explicitly call it and assign it to some variable within the class.

You could call `open` from inside the initializer if you want the connection to open when the singleton is created.

Another direction you could go is to leave `conn` and `open` both static so that `open` can access `conn`, and let the class itself be the singleton. Then you could eliminate the `shared` variable.

However, I think the best option would be to do as described above, making `conn` and `open` non-static, *and* get rid of the `shared` instance and instead just keep track of the `DBConnection` object that you create.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this in depth explanation of each piece.